# AngularJS: need to split/parse ng-options value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

A legacy database I am working with stores lookup values in a semi-colon separated list (within a single field/column in the table) - which worked fine as a data source for an ASP.NET. But for migrating to AngularJS - I've found no way to intercept the value and split it for separate options in the select element.

In the select drop down it simply shows (for example) "1 rep; 2 reps; 3 reps" etc.

Can anyone suggest how to split this value so the select options render vertically - each one in it's own option row?

This is how the select element looks now:

```
<select
ng-model="exerciseVals[$index].reps1" ng-options="value.REPS as value.REPS for (key,value) in lkps
></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-options` works on an array or an object.

If I understand your situation correctily, you're getting a large string from the server with semicolon-separated entries. You need to split it into an array.

```
$scope.lkps = stringFromServer.split(";");
```

Then in HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedVal" 
        ng-options="item for item in lkps">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try This , i have included in my code too !

[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7966/)

```
 <div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="tempCtrl">
    <select>
    <option ng-repeat="temp in tempdata">
    {{temp}}
   </option>
   </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

JS CODE

```
var myApp = angular.module('App', ["xeditable"]);
myApp.controller('tempCtrl',function ($scope) {
alert();
$scope.tempdata = ["1 rep","2 rep","3 rep"];
console.log($scope);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use angular filter :

```
<select ng-model ='select'  ng-options="item for item in 'd;g;f'|split:';'">
   <option value="">Nothing selected</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
myApp.filter('split',function(){

    return function(str,delimeter)
    {
 return str.split(delimeter);
    }
```

check [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dzuwg1xk/17/)